# Can't pass arguments to Spring Boot app running on Docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

I am trying to create a Docker image for my Spring Boot app.
In order to start the app I need to pass it some param to switch between the environments, locally I use this command :

```
java -Denv=local -jar my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But with Docker I never succeeded to pass the `env` param so it craches directly after container starts.

I tried `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Denv=prod","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/flad-rest.jar"]` and `[CMD ["-Denv=prod"]` but nothing works

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# Make port 9091 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 9091

# The application's jar file
ARG JAR_FILE=flad-rest/target/flad-rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar

# Add the application's jar to the container
ADD ${JAR_FILE} flad-rest.jar

# Run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/flad-rest.jar"]
```

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Denv=prod","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/flad-rest.jar"]` must work. Are you sure you have tried that?

Comment: You say you need to switch between the environments, but do you actually mean [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-profiles)?

Comment: @IvanAracki yes I tried that exactly the same way that you have done but I get : `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [fr.payet.flad.core.config.CoreConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'env' in value "classpath:datasource-${env}.properties"`

Comment: @Boris in my case I'm not using Spring Profiles because I need to load a certain property file.

Comment: In that case I recommend you to consider using [Multi-profile YAML Documents](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml).

Comment: Is `env` defined in the `application` properties file?

Comment: No it's not ! I think there is no need

Answer (score 2):

When using Docker you can use an OS environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` to specify which [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles) are active:

```
$ docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod" -p 9091:9091 -t my-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

or

```
$ docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev" -p 9091:9091 -t my-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

See [Using Spring Profiles](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/#_using_spring_profiles) section in the **Spring Boot with Docker** guide for more info.

Comment: my actual requirement is just to pass the argument `env` to the jar. Maybe later I will change it as you suggested with Spring Profiles or multi profile YAML docs.